Darren thought that working at the/a bank

John had a drinking problem in school. After he graduated, John's friend Darren used his connections to help him get a job at a bank. Darren thought that working at the/a bank would make John more responsible and help him quit drinking completely. Darren's friend Peter, who worked there as a manager, accepted John as a full-time employee.

Is either option acceptable in this case, or should the definite article "the" be used because the word "bank" has already been mentioned with the indefinite article "a"? If either can be used, what is the nuance? Thank you.

Either option would be acceptable, but the could suggest "the bank where Darren had connections" whereas a would mean "any bank" and refer to banks as having something relevant in common.

I think the is more likely (meaning the bank where Darren got a job, as mentioned in the previous sentence).

@KateBunting Although for the purpose of making him more responsible, any bank would probably do.

A bank job can be a good job. It might even the best bank job  you can imagine.

This question is similar to: The confusion between "The" or "A" article. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Either option is acceptable. They mean slightly different things, but not in a way that changes much about the story:
"Darren thought that working at a bank would make John more responsible" more or less means Darren thinks working at any bank would be a good idea for John.
"Darren thought that working at the bank would make John more responsible" more or less means Darren thinks working at this particular bank would be a good idea for John.
Darren could also hold both beliefs, and the only difference between the two sentences is which of those two very similar beliefs of Darren's the story is choosing to report on.
